# Jquery All divs move but need just one to move

Tags: php, jquery, html, draggable

I have this following code below.  It has div within one bigger div.  I only want the "#set" div to move, not the other divs.  But right now the user can move anything that's within a div.  How can I make it only move the big div "set"?

Header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<style>
  #set { clear:both; float:left; width: 368px;}
  p { clear:both; margin:0; padding:1em 0; }
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 
    stack: "#set div",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
          var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
          var need = ui.helper.data("need");

          console.log(pos_x);
          console.log(pos_y);
          console.log(need);

          //Do the ajax call to the server
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "updatecoords.php",
              data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
            })
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Body:

```
<div id="set">

<?

$getcoords = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coords WHERE needid=6");  
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcoords);
$x = $rows['x'];  
$y = $rows['y'];  

echo "

<div style='width: 175px; height: 350px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; background: white; position:fixed;left:".$x."px; top:".$y."px;' data-need='6' class='column'>

  <div class='portlet'>
    <div class='portlet-header'>Contacts</div>
    <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class='portlet'>
    <div class='portlet-header'>Notes</div>
    <div class='portlet-content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
";

?>

</div>
```

Comment: I think maybe there is something obvious getting missed here. Based on my understanding of your question, @arun-p-johnny's answer is right.  Perhaps your question is unclear?
A test for you to try, just to make sure things are working properly: make just '.portlet-content' draggable, and see what happens.

Comment: when I change it to: `$( "#portlet" ).draggable({ 
    stack: "#portlet",` it drags the first portlet and lets me change it but not the second.  The "#set" div is the big div around the other divs.  I want the code to move only it.  But it's moving all the divs in the code from my original code.

Comment: This should do it:
    `$('#set').not($('#set div')).draggable()`

Comment: Just saw your question to @Arun.  `$('#set').draggable()` widthout `stack:"#set div"` should work to. Try it without stack option to see if it works.

Comment: user1167442 your code didn't work either.  Look at the comments below on the answer and I've included a link for a demo of my full code and what's going on with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to move the direct children of `#set` not the `#set` element.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#set > div" ).draggable({ 
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
            var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
            var need = ui.helper.data("need");

            console.log(pos_x);
            console.log(pos_y);
            console.log(need);

            //Do the ajax call to the server
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "updatecoords.php",
                data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gVT4vffHv89WdMEVdI71?p=preview)

Comment: it stopped set from moving altogether...i couldnt move ant div then

Comment: would     stack: "#set div", have anything to do with it?

Comment: can you remove it and check

Comment: Check this http://plnkr.co/edit/OY9aVcFQpNNx5Dr7Mxbp?p=preview it looks fine to me

Comment: One Sec ... do you want to move the `#set` element or the direct children of `#set`

Comment: just the $set element.  Here's the full code and what it's doing http://plnkr.co/edit/a9TtaqGgzGpYq59dXxnK I want it to move the #set div and then move whatever is inside of it as well

Comment: I just tried @Arun's demo - and I altered it to `$('#set')` only - with the stack option as well - and it worked fine.